# Simple PHP file download / request page

Tags: php, download, get

I'm looking for a simple PHP-based download or "request" script that works in a fashion of download.php?file=zip.php

Ideally the page would say "you are requesting .zip" then wait five seconds before downloading  file. Is this possible?

Comment: This is not the place for "send me teh codez" type of questions. If you want some answers post concrete questions. If you want someone to do the coding for you go to some other web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only because this is easy, I will write the codes but SO is not for that, just if you have a bugg with your **previously-written code**.

```
<?php 
    $filename = $_GET["file"];
    if(isset($filename)){
        echo "You are downloading ".$filename;
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location='".$filename."';</script>";
    }else{
        echo "You havent selected a file to download";
    }
?>
```

Imagining the URL is download.php?file=hohoho.zip
it would output:

```
You are downloading hohoho.zip
<script type='text/javascript'>top.location='hohoho.zip';</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write a page in php, it's fully executed by the time the client receives it.  You could write some kind of wait function in JavaScript that runs on the client machine and then fetches the download.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with $_GET[] variable php. This maybe helpful to you 
http://www.hi5place.com/look/hide-file-location-using-php/2558